# execute the correct sql script in postgres 12.1.3 get the error output,where are my error

Tags: sql, postgresql

when i execute the sql script in postgres 12.1.3

```
select  'pg_dump -h localhost -d ' || d.datname || ' -U dba -v -O > d:\'|| d.datname || '_'|| to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'.sql' as backupscript
,'psql -h localhost -U dba '|| d.datname ||' < d:\'|| d.datname || '_'|| to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'.sql' as restorescript
, 'create database ' || d.datname || ' with owner ' || aa.username::text ||' ;'  as createdatabase
, ''
from pg_database d , current_user  as aa(username)
where d.datname not in ('postgres','template0','template1','template1')
```

the output is

```
select  'pg_dump -h localhost -d ' || d.datname || ' -U dba -v -O > d:\'|| d.datname || '_'|| to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'.sql' as backupscript
,'psql -h localhost -U dba '|| d.datname ||' < d:\'|| d.datname || '_'|| to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'.sql' as restorescript
, 'create database ' || d.datname || ' with owner ' || aa.username::text ||'
> ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'"
LINE 3: ...se ' || d.datname || ' with owner ' || aa.username::text ||'
                                                                      ^

> Time: 0.004s
```

[execute script in navicat 15.0.5, there is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiyfS.png)

Comment: The quotes are messed up. this part `' -U dba -v -O > d:\'` why are you doing `\'` ?

Comment: I try run your query then its successful. No error :D

Comment: i want contact string to generate backup database command then execute in windows